# SQL select the only rows with only a certain values in them

Tags: mysql, sql, row, unique, multiple-columns

i have the same problem here :[SQL select rows with only a certain value in them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6110565/sql-select-rows-with-only-a-certain-value-in-them)

but the solution that i have found work only for one value given, i mean that i want it to work for a number of values {2 or +}, for example :

```
Col 1 Col 2 Col 3
1       A     1
2       A     2
3       B     1
4       C     1
5       C     2
6       D     1 
7       C     3
```

I want to get all rows that  just contain  cols3 = 1 and cols3 =2 ONLY , (just values 1 and 2) and the output will be  : "A" for the table given, i dont want to have C because it has another values of cols 3 != of 1 or 2,
The solution in the link allows doing this for just one value , but i want to extend it to 2 value or plus , can someone help me please :D

Comment: And why would it not be "D"?

Comment: "D" only has col3 = 1?

Comment: D has only cols3=1 , it will be D if we have another row with 'D'--'2'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `conditional aggregation` for this:

```
select col2
from yourtable
group by col2 
having sum(col3=1) > 0 
  and sum(col3=2) > 0
  and sum(col3 not in (1,2)) = 0
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46f85/4)

Comment: this solution worked for me , and i was able to extend with many values , thx

Answer (score 0):

SELECT col 2
FROM TABLE
WHERE (col 3 =1
       OR col 3 =2)
  AND col 2 NOT IN
    (SELECT col 2
     FROM TABLE
     WHERE (col 3 <>2
            AND col 3 <> 1));