# Not getting the desired result (sql query)

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to obtain all rows that contain **processed = 1 and approved = 1** for the different ids **but** if the same id has any row with **processed = 0 and approved = 0** then, i dont want to obtain anything for that specific id.

This is what i want:

[image]

*Here is my query:*

```
   select * from table1 oa
    inner join table2 kio on oa.id = kio.id_table_1
    inner join table3 joi on kio.col3 = joi.col3_id_table_2
    where joi.processed = 1
    and joi.approved = 1
```

*SQL FIDDLE:*

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fc7266/3

I think the best way to solve this is using group by and having condition but it is not working for me

EDIT:

Another guy wanted to do this:
"get all rows that just contain cols3 = 1 and cols3 =2 ONLY , (just values 1 and 2) and the output will be : "A" for the table given, i dont want to have C because it has another values of cols 3 != of 1 or 2"

```
Col 1 Col 2 Col 3
1       A     1
2       A     2
3       B     1
4       C     1
5       C     2
6       D     1 
7       C     3
```

and he solved his problem by using this query:

```
select col2
from yourtable
group by col2 
having sum(col3=1) > 0 
  and sum(col3=2) > 0
  and sum(col3 not in (1,2)) = 0
```

Is it possible to do that in my case?

Comment: You want to just get `id` value from table1 ? Because GROUP BY will restrict the result-set to one row for a particular `id`. So getting all the rows from table 2 for a specific `id` won't happen if you use `Group By`

Comment: Also, what happens if an `id` have pair (1,0) or (0,1) for (processed, approved) in table 3 ? Do you still select that `id` ?

Comment: Not exactly but could you please tell me whats going on in the other case (Why the other guy used group by in the other case? - in my edit question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [Correlated Subquery with `Not Exists()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html):

```
select * from table1 oa
inner join table2 kio on oa.id = kio.id_table_1
inner join table3 joi on kio.col3 = joi.col3_id_table_2
where joi.processed = 1
and joi.approved = 1
and not exists (select 1 
                from table3 t3 
                where t3.processed = 0 
                      and t3.approved = 0 
                      and t3.col3_id_table_2 = joi.col3_id_table_2)
```

[DB Fiddle Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/adanvQ9JYtTVvbsqq5SBNh/0)

---

Since you want to understand the `GROUP BY` approach; it works on conditional filtering using `HAVING` clause. MySQL implictly typecasts a boolean result from a conditional expression, *i.e.*, true/false to 1/0. So, you can basically get all the `id` values, which has atleast one row with processed = 1 and approved = 1, but no row with processed = 0 and approved = 0, using the following:

```
SELECT col3_id_table_2 
FROM table3 
GROUP BY col3_id_table_2 
HAVING
  -- For every row in the group, check if processed = 1 and approved = 1
  -- If true, it gets typecasted to integer 1
  -- MySQL then sums them up. We need atleast one row, so > 0 condition
  SUM(t3.processed = 1 AND t3.approved = 1) > 0

  AND 

  -- For every row in the group, check if processed = 0 and approved = 0
  -- If false, it gets typecasted to integer 0
  -- MySQL then sums them up. We don't need a single such row, so = 0 condition
  SUM(t3.processed = 0 AND t3.approved = 0) = 0
```

Now, we can use this as a subquery (Derived Table) to get the `id` values, and then use it to get the corresponding rows from table1 and table2:

```
select * from table1 oa
inner join table2 kio on oa.id = kio.id_table_1
inner join 
(select col3_id_table_2
 from table3 
 group by col3_id_table_2
 having 
   sum(processed = 1 and approved = 1) > 0
   and sum(processed = 0 and approved = 0) = 0
 ) dt on dt.col3_id_table_2 = oa.id
```

[DB Fiddle Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/adanvQ9JYtTVvbsqq5SBNh/1)

Comment: Thank you for replying!. Dude,i've updated my question. Could you please explain that to me? Using group by?

Comment: @Neway check the updated answer. provides another approach and explanation using `group by`

Comment: Who downvoted ? Please explain. @Neway anything wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the extra condition:

```
select * from table1 oa
inner join table2 kio on oa.id = kio.id_table_1
inner join table3 joi on kio.col3 = joi.col3_id_table_2
where joi.processed = 1
  and joi.approved = 1
  and oa.id not in (
    select oa.id from table1 oa
    inner join table2 kio on oa.id = kio.id_table_1
    inner join table3 joi on kio.col3 = joi.col3_id_table_2
    where joi.processed = 0
      and joi.approved = 0
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for replying!.
Dude, is it possible to solve this by using group by?

Comment: When you *aggregate* (that is when using `GROUP BY`) you get grouped rows, not the flat data anymore: that is, you would get a different result.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37759228/sql-select-the-only-rows-with-only-a-certain-values-in-them. I was trying to do something like that but i failed

Comment: Dude, i've updated my question. I am a little confused